# how to get html page content send using a hidden field in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a solution to get HTML page content, for example like a header (for example `<h3>`) or a `<p>` or a `<div>`, and send it via a form?

```
<p id="test">
  <strong>Beispielveranstaltung<br />SAMSTAG, 14.01.2017 | 20:00 UHR |&nbsp;</strong><br />
  <strong>EINTRITT 12€</strong
</p>
```

- the form is embedded into the site
- the form got a hidden field with the name "event"

This is the javascript I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#event').load $("#test");
  });
</script>
```

I tried this too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#event') $("#test").val();
  });
</script>
```

---

I have to look closer whats going on there nothing 
of the supposed solution helps me.

I've done this as you suggested:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#event').val( $("#test").html() );
});
</script>
```

then i've added this `{event:caption}:{event:value}` to my "mail to admin" section...i see nothing happens. I can see only a ":" in the mail send to me

I'm using a RSFORM Component for Joomla

A similiar scenario with a script to get the document-title is working fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery('#Veranstaltung').val(document.title);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can get the content using either `text()` or `html()`. You can then send it using AJAX, or set it as the `val()` of a form input and submit a form as normal.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to put the content of the #test tag in your input #event:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#event').val( $("#test").html() );
  });
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure ...i've testet this suggestion with text() as well.
I don't know whats going on there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="event">
//Please use 'id' instead of 'name' attribute
<p id="test">
  <strong>Beispielveranstaltung<br />SAMSTAG, 14.01.2017 | 20:00 UHR |&nbsp;</strong><br />
  <strong>EINTRITT 12€</strong
</p>
</form>
```

then use script as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //you will get your html content here
    console.log(jQuery('#event').find('#test').html());
  });
</script>
```